# Search a listview programatically for app name

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, layout-inflater

Hi I am developing an android search app. I am displaying all app names installed on a phone on a listview programatically as below .

```
private void loadApps()
{
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

    final List<ResolveInfo> mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(mApps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));

    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this, mApps));
}
```

my BaseAdapter looks as below

```
public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    TextView textLable;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

    public AppsAdapter(Context context, List<ResolveInfo> mApps) 
    {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mApps = mApps;
    }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHandler handler;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.easeallapps_applist, null);
            handler = new ViewHandler();
            handler.textLable = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            convertView.setTag(handler);
        } 
        else 
        {
            handler = (ViewHandler)convertView.getTag();
        }
        ResolveInfo info = this.mApps.get(position);
        handler.textLable.setText(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
        return convertView;

    }
    class ViewHandler
    {
        TextView textLable;
    }
```

I want to include an Search EditText at the top of this listview for searching the apps. I am not sure how to do it. Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: post your activity code where you have created a listview programmatically

Comment: I am calling the laodapps() method onCreate. The above code itself generates the listview.

Comment: are you set your content View on onCreate()?

Comment: No. I am not using the setContentView().

Comment: Okay..So for that you have to set setTextFilterEnabled true for listView...

Answer (score 1):

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        loadApps(s);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

i hope this post is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks.Tried. But I am not using a setContentView and displaying listview programatically. Not sure where I need to include this code. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for you, all you need to read step by step and implement in your project.

below is the complete tutorials link for

[**Adding Search Functionality to ListView**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

[image]

Here is code snip.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch;
 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     
    // List view
    private ListView lv;
     
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
     
     
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         
        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
         
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
         
        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
         
        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }
             
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 
            }
             
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

once you get all the appname in mApps list.. Modify/ remove the name in mApps list which does not matchs with edittext test..

once you get the the final list, in your AppsAdapter class create a **setter for mApps**.. and set the data of mApps from your activity class and call the folowing

```
mListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. But how to programatically include the edittext at the top of the listview

Comment: assuming that your nt using listactivity ot Listfragment..if it is possible then add it in your layout bt u want to add it programatically then this is the code..LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout)
Edittext txt1 = new Edittext (MyClass.this);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);

Comment: I am not using the setContentView(). How do I include (R.id.mylayout) for it?

Comment: so your using listactivity I guess

Comment: yes. Is it possible to include an edittext on ListActivity or not?

Comment: yes you can as an header ... hope this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497465/setting-text-for-a-textview-in-listactivity

Comment: @sanjana you dont need any EditText, just use setTextFilterEnabled, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942421/android-what-does-settextfilterenabled-method-do

Comment: thankyou i didnt knw such feature exist.. on doing some reasearch i found a good tutorial which use it.. here is the link .. just in case you need it http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/settextfilterenabled/